# how to connect api.ai bot to a mysql database

Tags: mysql, machine-learning, nlp, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I'm developing an API.AI chat bot to integrate with a website. This also should be able to query from a MySQL database. 
What is the approach to implement this?

Comment: Divide the problem into pieces. Querying the mySQL database should be trivial. Working with the API.ai code, is up to you. You can use any web framework for the website. I am not sure what the question is at all? Can you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [Api.ai's fulfillment documentation](https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment#authentication).  Api.ai uses fulfillment webhooks, a URL you define, and then any intent you indicate should use the webhook will send a HTTP request to the webhook with all the relevant information about the user's query (any parameters, the intent, etc.).  You can then connect your fulfillment webhook to the database of your choice and map users queries to SQL queries, get the desired information and return it in a response to the user.

Please keep in mind that Api.ai HTTP requests timeout after 5 seconds, which means from the time Api.ai issues a request to the time that you send back a response must be less than 5 seconds.